# Jquery como trabajar con each index

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp

tengo una duda sobre mi Jquery , con este escript envio informacion a un correo , el problema es que se me estan enviando 11 correos con la informacion distinta , eso esta bien pero lo que quiero es que toda esa informacion se me resuma en un solo correo , me han recomendado realizar una condicion con el indice.

```
// Se enviara correo de notif. a Mantenimiento
var fecini  = "<%=fInicio%>";
var fecfin  = "<%=fTermino%>";
var func    = "normal";
var fechaNotif = "<%=fTermino%>";

$.ajax({
    async:false,    
    cache:false,   
    dataType:"html",
    type: 'POST',   
    url: "rep3_notificacion.asp",
    data: {
            fecini:fecini
          , fecfin:fecfin  
          , werks:centro          
          , stort:emplazamiento       
          , func:func           
    }, 
    success:  function(respuesta){  
        //$("#mostrarRep").html(respuesta);
        $.post("rep3_notificacion_email.asp", { werks:centro , stort:emplazamiento , tablas:contenidoCorreo, fechaNotif:fechaNotif }, function(data) {
          }).done(function() {
    // enviar mensaje de ejecucion correcta
            alert("Enviado correctamente");
          }).fail(function() {
         alert("Error al enviar correo");
      });
    },
    beforeSend:function(){},
    error:function(objXMLHttpRequest){}
});

 }
```

Comment: que valores tienen: var centros = [<%=centrosNotif%>];
var emplaza = [<%=empNotif%>]; ya que each hacer un loop al igual que un for estas enviado el valor 0 de centro y el valor 0 de emplaza y asi sucesibamente el valor 1 y el 1 por cada correo

Comment: ¿Qué ocurrió con el código? No está en la pregunta.

Comment: perdon , se me habia borrado el codigo , lo eh puesto otra vez

Comment: por que estás metiendo otra consulta pasandole los mismos resultados a otra pagina??